# facebook invitations through android app

Tags: android, facebook

I am developing an android app. Is it possible to integrate Facebook invitations into my app? Something like "Rounds app" : https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rounds.android
because this app contains this function and we are able to invite Facebook friends through it.
I searched and all I found was that I can integrate the Facebook invitation function in games. (but "Rounds" app, is not a game)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook consider all to be apps.

You create an app in Facebook developer and you can use it as game or as an application.

Create the request as if it was game.

I suggest you try this page: [Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/send-requests/).